# how to segregate the documents from live server to the new documents server without disturbing data at live server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, bigdata, erp

I have a SQL server database which has around 5000 records in one of the tables including pdf file and another table around 10000 records of images.
I want to upgrade it and for that, need more space and I want to segregate the database to document database. Is there any method or technique that I can use for that?

Comment: Are you saying that you'd like to take these records and transfer them to some sort of document storage? Would you mind specifying which type you'd like to migrate to?

Comment: Do you even need to store those files in a database? Hosting them on a CDN would prevent them taking up that space, and you'd be able to cache them more easily.

Comment: there is an SQL server database which right now all the report files saved on it as byte data to the database and there are no available files for that reports. now due to changing the whole system to ERP, I want to save those files without interrupting the online server to files and then save that files to the different server. if the application were offline I would write a program to create pdf reports and save them on the server and remove from the database. but now if I do that the server will be overload and the app should get offline for this. so any opinion?